# Taylor series expansion of $\ln(1+x)$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I want to show that $$\log(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + R_{3} = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + R_{4}$$

with $R_{3}$ and $R_{4}$ found in the Lagrange form of the remainder in Taylor's theorem, and hence prove:

$$ x - \frac{x^2}{2} < \log(1+x) < x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} $$ for all $x>0$. The hint states to use $f(x)=\log(x)$ with $a=1$ in Taylor's theorem.

By doing that, I'm not sure how one gets the term $\log(1+x)$. Think I'm being rather silly here but  just can't spot my error....

Comment: I changed $log(1+x)$ to $\log(1+x)$.  That is standard usage.  It not only prevents $\log$ from being italicized as if it were a product of three variables; it also provides proper spacing before and after $\log$ in expressions like $a\log b$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

What is the statement of Taylor's Theorem?

Comment: $$f(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}f ^{(k)}(a) (x-a)^k$$ but it says to use f(x) as log(x)...

Comment: And what if you stick in $x+1$ for $x$?